# how do i create/import a clojure project from github in netbeans?

Tags: git, netbeans, clojure

how do i create a project (a clojure project) in netbeans on windows given that i have the original project on git hub (http://github.com/babo/ai-contest-planet-wars-clj). i want this project in netbeans so i can make use of the enclojure plugin

thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very elegant at this, I clone git projects and then say new project from existing sources. the nbgit plugin would help keep the cloning process within netbeans.